# Django form validation through models.py

Tags: python, django

I am trying to make the action of send an automatic email after the admin hits the "save" button after create an object in a particular Model.

One way to do that is to validate the form in the models.py file. The question is how can I do that? I have tried that in views.py as shown below:

```
def admin_email_sender(request):
    if request.method == 'POST':
        form = FaturaForm(request.POST)
        if form.is_valid():
            subject = 'Notificação de fatura'
            from_email = settings.DEFAULT_FROM_EMAIL
            to_email = [str(form.cleaned_data['cliente'].email)]
            signup_message = 'Olá, ' + str(form.cleaned_data['cliente']) + '\n' + \
                         'Você possui uma fatura para pagar até o dia ' + \
                         str(form.cleaned_data['dia']) + ' de ' + str(form.cleaned_data['mes']) + ' de ' + str(form.cleaned_data['ano'])
            send_mail(subject,
                      signup_message,
                      from_email,
                      to_email,
                      fail_silently=False)
```

Maybe it is possible to do it with other ways.
Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use django [signals](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.1/topics/signals/), as per your requirement you can use [post_save](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.1/ref/signals/#django.db.models.signals.post_save).

When you form is valid and model saved successfully, then `post_save` event triggered imminently and run the function that you connect to it.

This is very useful method to do task like that. Suggest tutorial - https://simpleisbetterthancomplex.com/tutorial/2016/07/28/how-to-create-django-signals.html

Still have any doubts comment it.

Comment: Thanks, dude! After all I did create a form with a clean function that validates the form. In admin.py I called that form and it worked perfectly as I wanted. Your link is also very helpful and I will use that in the future if needed!